# Receive S3::Error::SignatureDoesNotMatch by using Paperclip with “s3” on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, paperclip

I am working with Paperclip and AWS and can successfully get the upload to work on my local host. The problem I run into is when I upload the app to Heroku I get:

```
AWS::S3::Errors::SignatureDoesNotMatch (The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Ch
```

eck your key and signing method.)

Locations.rb

```
has_attached_file :photo,
                :styles => { :thumb => "150x150#", :medium => "200x200#", :small => "50x50"},
                :path => ":attachment/:id/:style.:extension",
                :s3_domain_url => "adsimgstore.s3.amazonaws.com",
                :storage => :s3,
                :s3_credentials => S3_CREDENTIALS,
                :bucket => 'adsimgstore',
                :s3_permissions => :public_read,
                :convert_options => { :all => "-auto-orient" }
```

s3 initialize

```
# initializers/s3.rb
if Rails.env == "production"
 # set credentials from ENV hash
 S3_CREDENTIALS = { :access_key_id => ENV['S3_KEY'], :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET'],   :bucket => "adsimgstore"}
else
  # get credentials from YML file
  S3_CREDENTIALS = Rails.root.join("config/s3.yml")
end
```

I have followed the Heroku tutorial https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3 and added all keys

Any suggestions?

```
 AWS::S3::Errors::SignatureDoesNotMatch (The request signature we calculated does not match the     signature you provided. Ch
eck your key and signing method.):
2012-05-01T18:01:02+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-05-01T18:01:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/locations_controller.rb:76:in `block in     update'
2012-05-01T18:01:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/locations_controller.rb:75:in `update'
2012-05-01T18:01:02+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Answer (score 1):

- check if your environment variables match

if you followed the heroku tutorial your environment variables would be `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`.

run `heroku config` to check your env variables.

- no `:bucket` in Credentials

You put the `:bucket` option in the `S3_CREDENTIALS`-hash in the `initializers/s3.rb` file. the bucket-option doesn't belong here - you already set it in the `has_attached_file` method.

Comment: My environment variable do match the Heroku config file. That is why I am not understanding why the error is occuring

Comment: Not sure if this would make a difference...but I see that Heroku has "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" and in my s3.yml file I have "access_key_id"......could the lack of "aws" be causing this issue?

Comment: your YAML file only gets parsed in development and therefore has no influence on heroku. if you type `heroku config` the variables 'S3_KEY' and 'S3_SECRET' have to be set.

Comment: Right now I it is displaying "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"...I am going to change it to S3 as you mentioned. Strange because the setup from Heroku has AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID

Comment: Was hoping it would work but didnt. Getting "AWS::S3::Errors::SignatureDoesNotMatch in Devise::RegistrationsController#update"

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found this https://rubygems.org/gems/paperclip-aws and it seemed to have fixed my issue with my current setup